# How does $\sum p(k)$ grow asymptotically where $p(k)$ is the smallest prime factor of $k$?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Define $p(k)$ to be the smallest prime $p$ dividing $k$. Define $A(n)=\sum_{k=2}^n p(k)$. How does $A(n)$ grow asymptotically? I am wondering how exactly the naive algorithm for finding all primes less than and equal to $n$ by testing for divisibiity of all numbers less than $k$ for each $k<n$ actually performs. It's very easy to see it is $O(n^2)$ but there must be a better bound.

Comment: Use the result for the product $\prod_k p(k)$ [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435078/growth-rate-of-product-of-smallest-prime-factors). I suppose your definition of $p(k)$ should be the smallest prime dividing $k$, not $n$.

Comment: It must be at least $\Omega\left(\dfrac{n^2}{\log n}\right)$, since between $\frac n2$ and $n$ there are $\pi(n)-\pi(n/2)\in\Theta\left(\dfrac{n}{\log n}\right)$ primes each of size $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, how would I use that result? I can't think of anything.

Comment: The logarithm of $\prod_kp(k)$ gives $\sum_k \log(p(k))$, which has been discussed [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435078/growth-rate-of-product-of-smallest-prime-factors).

Comment: Ah, so use Jensen's to write $$ \log(\sum p(k)) -\log(n) \leq \sum n \log(p(k))?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q$ denote a prime, and let
$$
s(n) = \sum_{q\le n} q = \frac{n^2}{2\log n} + O\left(\frac{n^2}{\log^2 n}\right)
$$
as [discussed on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63412/upper-bounds-for-the-sum-of-primes-n). Clearly
$
s(n) = \sum_{q\le n} p(q) \le A(n)
$.

Define the sets
$$
S_q(n) = \{1<k\le n, p(k)=q \}
$$
If $\sqrt{n}<q\le n$ then $\left\vert S_q(n)\right\vert = 1$, and for every $q$
$$
\left\vert S_q(n)\right\vert \le \left\lfloor\frac{n}{q}\right\rfloor
$$
since this counts all multiples of $q$ in the range, which must be a superset of $S_q$. Hence
$$
\begin{align}
A(n) & = \sum_{q\le n} q\left\vert S_q(n)\right\vert \\
& \le \sum_{q\le \sqrt{n}} q\left\lfloor\frac{n}{q}\right\rfloor + \sum_{\sqrt{n}<q\le n} q \\
& \le \sum_{q\le \sqrt{n}} q \left(\frac{n}{q}\right) + \sum_{q\le n} q \\
& = \sum_{q\le \sqrt{n}} n + s(n) \\
& = n\pi\left(\sqrt{n}\right) + s(n) \\
& = s(n) + O\left(\frac{n^{3/2}}{\log n}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $\pi(\cdot)$ is the prime counting function.
Thus $A(n)$ has asymptotic behavior similar to $s(n)$,
$$
A(n) = \frac{n^2}{2\log n} + O\left(\frac{n^2}{\log^2 n}\right)
$$

Comment: Great answer! Two things: I think you meant $q$ instead of $p(q)$ in the second expression for $s(n)$. Also, this only gives an upper bound on $A(n)$. From the comments, this is enough to show that the growth is exactly $n^2/log(n)$ up to a constant. However, does the constant $1/2$ actually hold?

Comment: @nayrb $p(q)=q$ for any prime $q$, and that expression gives a lower bound $s(n)=\sum_q p(q) \le A(n)$ because it is the sum of $p(k)$ restricted only to primes in the range. So $s(n) \le A(n) \le s(n) + o(n^2/\log^2 n)$, and yes, the constant multiple is $1/2$.

Comment: Okay, got it! All clear now. Thanks!