# Asymptotic Approximation towards Sum of the Composite Number's Smallest Prime Factor

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-factorization

I wonder if there is any asymptotic approximation towards the sum of the smallest prime factor of the composite numbers which are less than $n$. This is also the sum of terms whose index is not prime in Sequence A020639(OEIS).

I know it won't grow faster than $O(n^\frac{3}{2})$, as a composite number $n$ must have a prime factor less than $\sqrt n$, but I want a lower bound or a more accurate approximation with the same order as the sum for time complexity analysis use.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(n)$ denote the smallest prime factor of $n$, and when $q$ is prime define the set
$$
R_q(x) = \{ q< n\le x\colon p(n) = q \}.
$$
The OP is then asking about the sum
$$
\sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ n\text{ composite}}} p(n) = \sum_{q\le x} q\cdot\#R_q(x).
$$
Note that the sum on the right-hand side can be restricted to $q\le\sqrt x$, as the OP pointed out.

[Zander's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1224635/16078) to a similar question points out that $\#R_q(x) \le \frac xq$ and that therefore
$$
\sum_{q\le\sqrt x} q\cdot\#R_q(x) \le \sum_{q\le\sqrt x} x = x\pi(\sqrt x) \ll \frac{x^{3/2}}{\log x}.
$$

On the other hand, $R_q(x)$ includes all numbers of the form $qr$ where $r$ is prime and $q\le r\le \frac xq$, and so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{q\le\sqrt x} q\cdot\#R_q(x) &\ge \sum_{q\le\sqrt x} q \bigl( \pi(\tfrac xq) - \pi(q) \bigl).
\end{align*}
When $q\le\frac12\sqrt x$ we have $\tfrac xq \ge 4q$ and thus $\pi(\tfrac xq) \ge (4-o(1)) \pi(q)$; consequently,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{q\le\sqrt x} q\cdot\#R_q(x) &\gg \sum_{q\le\frac12\sqrt x} q \pi(\tfrac xq) \gg \sum_{q\le\frac12\sqrt x} q \frac{x/q}{\log(x/q)} \\
&\ge \frac x{\log x} \sum_{q\le\frac12\sqrt x} 1 = \frac x{\log x} \pi(\tfrac12\sqrt x) \gg \frac{x^{3/2}}{(\log x)^2}.
\end{align*}
I suspect this lower bound is the correct order of magnitude, since the lower bound of $\#R_q(x)$ is tight when $q>\sqrt[3]x$.

Comment: I drew a diagram that shows the ratio $\frac{sum}{\frac{x^{3/2}}{(\log x)^2}}$ along with n( [here](https://box.nju.edu.cn/f/0000196bb5c74f249c65/) ), and the ratio shows a clear decreasing trend, which indicates your lower bound may be the very tight one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it is possible that $R_q(x)$ contains some almost primes too, so I conjecture this order to be something like $x^{3/2}(\log\log x)^a/(\log x)^2$ for some positive integer $a$.